# Pull multiple xpath values into a single cell using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull the price from [Sam's Club's website](https://www.samsclub.com/p/purina-cat-chow-indoor-dry-cat-food-hairball-healthy-weight/P03003663?xid=plp_product_1) into a spreadsheet (for grocery price comparison purposes). There is no element that contains the full price without additional text.

These are the elements from the website:

```
<span class="Price-group" title="current price: $22.98">
<span class="visuallyhidden">current price: $22.98</span>
<span class="Price-currency" aria-hidden="true">$</span>
<span class="Price-characteristic" aria-hidden="true">22</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="Price-mark">.</span>
<span aria-hidden="true" class="Price-mantissa">98</span>
```

I know how to pull in a single xpath (see my formula at the bottom of this post), but I cannot figure out how to either A) eliminate all of the text from "Price-group" or B) Combine "Price-characteristic", "Price-mark", and "Price-mantissa" into a single cell so that it appears as a single value (I can handle the formatting at that point).

I tried using a pipe to pull multiple xpaths in, but it resulted in the error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B101". This is what I tried (eliminating the spaces before & after the pipe only resulted in the same error, just referencing a different cell):
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IMPORTXML(TO_TEXT(F100), "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]/span/span[3] | /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]/span/span[5]","")))`

My base formula, which works (The URL for IMPORTXML is stored in another cell, which is referenced):
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IMPORTXML(TO_TEXT(F100), "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[1]/span/span[3]","")))`

Here is a copy of part of the spreadsheet that I am working on. On the "HEB" page, the price pulls in because they have it as a single element on their website. On the "Sam's Club" page, I am having trouble getting the same result.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xPRwi0Y0wISclyaVDvCCVEaocTtpzAHu5VmHs-wpn80/edit?usp=sharing

If this was answered sufficiently in a previous thread, I would greatly appreciate a link; I've not been able to find anything that helps. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the value of `22.98` from the URL of `https://www.samsclub.com/p/purina-cat-chow-indoor-dry-cat-food-hairball-healthy-weight/P03003663?xid=plp_product_1` using `IMPORTXML`.

In this case, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=JOIN("",IMPORTXML("https://www.samsclub.com/p/purina-cat-chow-indoor-dry-cat-food-hairball-healthy-weight/P03003663?xid=plp_product_1", "//span[@class='Price-characteristic' or @class='Price-mark' or @class='Price-mantissa']"))*1
```

- In this sample formula, the values of `span` tag of `Price-characteristic`, `Price-mark` and `Price-mantissa` are retrieved and those are joined.

#### Testing:

When this sample formula is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a sample formula for the URL of `https://www.samsclub.com/p/purina-cat-chow-indoor-dry-cat-food-hairball-healthy-weight/P03003663?xid=plp_product_1`. So, when you change the URL, the formula might not be able to be used. So, please be careful about this.

Comment: This worked! And it does work for other pages on the website (at least, the pages with prices that aren't added by javascript). I appreciate the assist.

Comment: @Amy Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.